# MySQL query that grabs information from a table, and gets a count of a related table. Not including all records

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to run a query which grabs **all courses**.  Each row (course) should also have a **user_count**.

Let me show my table structure real quick.  I have two tables of relevance. This doesn't show all the fields for these tables, just the relevant info.

```
COURSE
id
title
desc

USER_COURSE
id
user_id (fk)
course_id (fk)
```

My first stab at this was to create the following query:

```
SELECT course.title, course.desc, COUNT(*) as `user_count` 
FROM (`course`) 
JOIN `user_course` ON `user_course`.`course_id` = `course`.`id` 
GROUP BY `user_course`.`user_id`
```

The problem with this query is that it will only show courses which has records in the user_course table.  Pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Key points:**

1. `count(*)` should be `COUNT(user_course.user_id)` as you are counting  number of users per course
2. ON condition must be wrapped by parenthesis
3. Use group by `course.id` as you are grouping the result on per course basis.

See the query bellow.

```
    SELECT course.title, 
           course.desc, 
           COUNT(`user_course`.`user_id`) AS `user_count` 
    FROM   `course` 
           JOIN `user_course` 
             ON ( `user_course`.`course_id` = `course`.`id` ) 
    GROUP  BY `course`.`id`
```

Comment: shiplu, this is correct, except i had to do "left outer join" instead of "join".  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a left outer join.
Instead of 'join', write 'left outer join'.

Also wrap the count in isnull(count(*),0) to capture no records as a 0 value

Comment: SELECT course.title, course.desc, ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) as `user_count` 
FROM (`course`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user_course` ON `user_course`.`course_id` = `course`.`id` 
GROUP BY `user_course`.`user_id` correct?